# Label not changing text in a hangman game c#

Tags: c#

So im making a hangman gam3 it worked now im trying to make it w 2 players it aint working
He4e is the code for everybutton (letter)
When he clicks it

```
if (label13.Text == "Player 1 Guess")
        {



            if (Fullword.Contains(button2.Text))
            {
                char[] temp = Underscore_Word.ToCharArray();
                char[] found = Fullword.ToCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < found.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (found[i] == button2.Text.ElementAt(0))
                    {

                        temp[i] = button2.Text.ElementAt(0);
                    }
                }

                Underscore_Word = new string(temp);
                PrintLabel();


            }
            else
            {
                faux++;
            }
            if (faux < 7)
            {

                pictureBox1.Image = images[faux];
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "you lose !!! ";
                User.score--;
                label7.Text = "Score of " + Methods.displayName + ":  " + User.score.ToString();
                label2.Visible = true;
                label2.Text = "The word was :" + "\"" + Fullword + "\" ";
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.SoundLocation = "lose.wav";
                player.Play();
            }
            if (Underscore_Word.Equals(Fullword))
            {
                label1.Text = "You Win!!";

                User.score++;
                label7.Text = "Score of " + Methods.displayName + ":  " + User.score.ToString();

                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.SoundLocation = "appllaud.wav";
                player.Play();

            }
            label13.Text = "Player 2 Guess";
    else
    {

        if (Fullword.Contains(button2.Text))
        {
            char[] temp = Underscore_Word.ToCharArray();
            char[] found = Fullword.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < found.Length; i++)
            {
                if (found[i] == button2.Text.ElementAt(0))
                {

                    temp[i] = button2.Text.ElementAt(0);
                }
            }

            Underscore_Word = new string(temp);
            PrintLabel();


        }
        else
        {
            faux_player2++;
        }
        if (faux_player2 < 7)
        {

           pictureBox2.Image = images[faux_player2]; 
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "you lose !!! ";
            User.score--;
            label14.Text = "Score of " + Methods.displayName_playertwo + ":  " + User.score_Player2.ToString();
            label2.Visible = true;
            label2.Text = "The word was :" + "\"" + Fullword + "\" ";
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = "lose.wav";
            player.Play();
        }
        if (Underscore_Word.Equals(Fullword))
        {
            label1.Text = "You Win!!";

            User.score_Player2++;
            label14.Text = "Score of " + Methods.displayName_playertwo + ":  " + User.score_Player2.ToString(); ;

            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = "appllaud.wav";
            player.Play();

        }



        label13.Text = "Player 1 Guess";

    }
```

im having problems with the label its staying player 1 guess its alternating when the player gets a wrong guess please help

Comment: C# offers multiple technologies to build UIs. Which one are you using? WinForms? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Yes windows forms

Comment: check your braces near label13.Text = "Player 2 Guess"; I think there is a } missing before "else"

Answer (score 0):

You are messing a `}` after the `label13.Text = "Player 2 Guess";` before the `else`

```
if (label13.Text == "Player 1 Guess")
{
    // code ....
}
else
{
   // code ....
}
```

I would also Advice you to try to write cleaner code and try to not repeat yourself.

Comment: Not there is A } I Forgot to copy it